# Initialize Tensor Variable no elements only shape

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow

I want to initialize the tensor variable array to store the value through `tf.concat`.
With dimension is (?,), the initial is `tf.Variable([])`.
How about with dimension is (?,512)?
Thank you very much!

Comment: The shape of variables in TensorFlow must be fully known at graph construction time. There is no support for dynamically sized variables.

Comment: Thank you very much!. But I refer the situation with initializing the array with shape `(?,)`,rank of array is 1, `tf.Variable([])` be used Okie so I want with the shape array is `(?,?)` or `(?,512)`, rank of array is 2.

Comment: Do you mean like `tf.Variable([[]])`? Or `tf.Variable([[0] * 512])`?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.
when I set `tf.Variable([])`, I get array `(?,)`
So, I want create array with shape `(?,512) or (?,?)`. How to set with tf.Variable().
Thank you very much!

Comment: I successfully make it.
`#Initialize Variable
output_list_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,512]),dtype=tf.float32)
#Add vector
output_list_1 = tf.concat([output_list_1,added_vectors])
#Cheat remove the first redundant vector
m = tf.range(1, tf.shape(center_features)[0], 1)
center_feature = tf.gather(center_features,m)`

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I hadn't understood your question at first, I see what you meant now. Note you can post an answer to your own question and accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully make it

```
#Initialize Variable
center_features= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,512]),dtype=tf.float32) 
#Add vector 
center_features= tf.concat([center_features,added_vectors]) 
#Cheat remove the first redundant vector
m = tf.range(1, tf.shape(center_features)[0], 1) 
center_feature = tf.gather(center_features,m)
```